# How do I make the matlab ISO from 3 separate tarballs?

Tags: tar, matlab

I've downloaded Matlab for Linux, and it's 3 tar files, that I've to extract to get an ISO file. the problem is that it if I extract anyone of them I get an error. 
any idea?

Comment: Are the files named sequentially?  For example: file.tar, file.01, file.02 or file01.tar, file02.tar, file03.tar. If so, you should be able to double click on the first one and it  will auto extract the others along with it into your ISO file.

Comment: tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: can you write the three names of the files and what command you are executing (command line or GUI)?

Comment: So I would think that if you double click on the first file in the sequence, R2012a_UNIX 001.tar, then you should get the Archive Manager (file-roller) to open and extract your .iso file. This is assuming all three files are in the same folder. If you're not, then maybe the download was corrupted and you should download again (or see if there checksums to verify the integrity of the files). Or, less likely but possible,  maybe the tar/libtar0 packages you have installed [can't handle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1325910/462002) the files that were tarred with a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I got it now, if anyone still need the solution :

```
cat data.tar.001 data.tar.002 data.tar.003 > data.tar
```

With this command I'm making a "big" file named data.tar composed of the three other files.